# Verb meaning "selling charitably"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What term can you use to describe the act of "selling something charitably"?

"Donated" is close, but it is referring to giving something away. "Graciously sold" is too wordy. I'm thinking of using the word in this sentence, for example:

> Although it was the stall owner's very last orange, and he loved
>   oranges very much, he __ it to the young orphan for only 20 cents.

Comment: Are you sure you mean selling?  I think you mean giving.

Comment: I mean selling, but I'm not sure how to say it :)

Comment: He would sell it to the orphan at a reduced price?  In what sense do you mean he sold it charitably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a word that means exactly what you wish to say.

Rather, I would convey that it is an act of charity yet still at a price.

For example:

[**Bestow**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bestow) would be an excellent word here.

> The stall's owner, in a rare act of personal charity, decided to bestow his very last orange onto the young orphan for a mere 20 cents.

Bestow usually means to give a major gift, but here its use is nearly ironic.  Because, let's face it, he isn't being *entirely* charitable here.  He didn't just *give* it to the kid.  So, I think you need to highlight that.

That is, of course, unless there is a cultural notion of allowing the child to save face, or something of that nature.

Comment: @BlueIce No problem.  I think you see why I questioned selling...

Comment: Definitely. I didn't want it to seem overly gracious, so this is a good fit.